# Application insights: loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights deprecated in .net core 2.2.0

Tags: .net, azure, logging, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

In .net core 2.1.1, registering the application insights using:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration); //register InstrumentationKey
    ...
}

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
 {
     ...
     loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices, LogLevel.Information); 
     ...
 }
```

But, when I'm including this in .net core 2.2.0, I'm getting the warning:

> 'ApplicationInsightsLoggerFactoryExtensions.AddApplicationInsights(ILoggerFactory,
>   IServiceProvider, LogLevel)' is obsolete: 'Use
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsightsLoggingBuilderExtensions.AddApplicationInsights
>   from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights package'

I have included the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights package` and used like this:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
 {
     ...
     ApplicationInsightsLoggingBuilderExtensions.AddApplicationInsights(...//some params//);
     ...
 }
```

This doesn't let me defined the logging level for application insights.
  How can I define logging level in .net core 2.2.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please take a look at this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#aspnet-core-applications)

If it's a .net core web project, you can use following code to set log level in program.cs:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .ConfigureLogging(
        builder =>
        {

            builder.AddApplicationInsights("app insights instrumentation key");

            // You can set log level here
            builder.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>
                             ("", LogLevel.Information);
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the categories log level using the following code snippet

```
builder.Logging.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>(nameof(CategoryName), LogLevel.Trace)
```